# Как изменить внешний вид Navigation drawer activity?

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer

После создания Navigation drawer activity у нас есть 3 вертикальные полоски и, соответственно меню, а так же, справа, есть три точки. Зачем они нужны-то? Как их удалить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Справа за тремя точками кроется меню. Найдите в вашей Activity функцию `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, и там вы найдете его создание. Не нужно - удалите.

Подробнее здесь: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html